# Text Pattern into Data Frame

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
text = '''
12/2/2023
Deposit
USD
10
Complete
15/2/2023
Deposit
USD
15
Complete
'''
x = text.split()
y=pd.DataFrame(x)
print(y)
```

I want convert this into data frame with colums 'date','txn_type','curr','Amt','status', any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reshape the split text

```py
x = np.array(text.split()).reshape(-1, 5)
y = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['date','txn_type','curr','Amt','status'])
```

```
print(y)

        date txn_type curr Amt    status
0  12/2/2023  Deposit  USD  10  Complete
1  15/2/2023  Deposit  USD  15  Complete
```

Comment: this! i think it's the cleanest possible solution